# 全てのリモートリポジトリをfast-forward可能な範囲で同期したい

Tags: git

作業開始前に全てのリモートブランチやタグを完全に同期し、トラッキングしているローカルブランチも`fast-forward`できる範囲で同期したいのですが、`git pull --all --prune --ff-only`を実行しようとすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
$ git --version
git version 2.2.1

$ git pull --all --prune --ff-only
error: unknown option `ff-only'
usage: git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
   or: git fetch [<options>] <group>
   or: git fetch --multiple [<options>] [(<repository> | <group>)...]
   or: git fetch --all [<options>]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    ...
```

やりたいことは、

- 全てのリモートリポジトリについて、リモートブランチとタグを、削除も含めて完全に同期する
- 全てのローカルブランチについて、追跡しているブランチが`fast-forward`でマージ可能ならマージして同期する
- リモートブランチの移動・削除以外について安全（ローカルブランチの削除や破壊的移動が起きない）

です。これを正しく行うにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？　できるだけ簡潔に実行したいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やりたいことを実現するための回答ではありませんが、pull は fetch のオプションより merge のオプションを先に指定する必要があります。なので、次のようにするととりあえずコマンドは通るようになります。

```
git pull --ff-only --all --prune
```

ただ、これでも

> 全てのローカルブランチについて、追跡しているブランチがfast-forwardでマージ可能ならマージして同期する

を実現することはできないと思います。チェックアウトせずにローカルブランチへマージすることはできなかったように思うので。

Comment: そんなことでしたか、ありがとうございます！　チェックアウトしないとマージできないのなら、２番目を簡単に実現するのは難しそうですね……。ひとまずはこれで我慢することにします。

Answer (score 0):

エラーを見る限り、オプションスイッチが廃止されたのではないでしょうか。
Git2.0以降ではコンフィグの設定でFast forward onlyの設定ができるようです。

- http://qiita.com/massa142/items/16868ed6657831d69411